# How to update one field in different condition

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE `products_description` SET 
`products_name` = 'Name 1' WHERE language_id = 1 AND products_id = 2249,
`products_name` = 'Name 2' WHERE language_id = 2 AND products_id = 2249,
`products_name` = 'Name 3' WHERE language_id = 7 AND products_id = 2249 ;
```

I need use one query update 3 rows.
Thank you!

Comment: Why only one query?  What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Because remote server very slow when running many queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :-

```
UPDATE products_description
SET products_name = (
  CASE language_id 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Name 1'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Name 2'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'Name 3'
  END
)
WHERE products_id = 2249;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the exact syntax for mysql, but this is what I would do in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE `products_description` 
   SET `products_name` = CASE WHEN language_id = 1 THEN 'Name 1' 
                              WHEN language_id = 2 THEN 'Name 2' 
                              WHEN language_id = 7 THEN 'Name 3' 
                              ELSE `products_name`
                         END
 WHERE products_id = 2249 ;
```